# Unique value error without unique parameter

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-admin

I'm trying to be able to create `Accounts` with usernames unique for each `Server`

```
class Server(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

right now I'm getting the

`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "zuya_aaccount_username_5f0a17d4_uniq"`

When I create a non-unique `account_name` it doesn't show any problem

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) to specify that two (or more fields) together should be unique:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['server', 'account_name'],
                name='unique_username_per_server'
            )
        ]
```

This thus means that for the same server, no two `Account`s with the same `account_name` can exist and vice versa.

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of the [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) meta option:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['server', 'account_name']]
```

Comment: That absolutely did it! Thank you